# Why is Azure pinging my site?

Tags: wordpress, web-crawlers, robots.txt, azure

I have noticed more and more, traffic from IPs assigned to Microsoft Azure/Microsoft Corporation hitting my WordPress site many times a day.  It's direct traffic to just the home and privacy policy pages using a wide variety of IPs.

Any idea why this is happening or how I can stop it?

Comment: What is the reason you want to stop it, specifically? Is it interfering with your site's performance, or causing you to pay for extra bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that bing is trying to index your site and as you know when a search engine wants to index a site they look for the privcy police pages too, so maybe you are using a seo addon on Wordpress or an addon that has seo futures in it